# How to store different site parameters in database with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There are a lot of ways to store site preferences in database. But what if I need to manage datatypes. So some preferences will be boolean, others strings, others integers.

How can I organize such store?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a gem that does exactly this, and recently updated it for Rails 3:

For Rails 3:

http://github.com/paulca/configurable_engine

For Rails 2.3.x

http://github.com/paulca/behavior

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite lazy with preferences and store the data as serialized JSON or YAML Hashes. Works really well, and generally preserves the data types as well.

Comment: What about using a schemaless database instead?
It'll perform much better, and is easier to query with JSON hashes.

Comment: You could, but then you need to either ditch your RDBMS for everything, or run the two together increasing your costs. Performance of pulling a string from the database to deserialize is pretty good, especially when using JSON and the JSON gem. You will still have the deserialization overhead using a db like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I used a single table with a single row, and each column representing one preference. This makes it possible to have different datatypes.

To be able to retrieve a preference, I overrode `method_missing` to be able to retrieve the preference value directly from the class name without requiring an instance, something like this:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@instance = self.first

  def self.instance
    @@instance
  end

  def self.method_missing(method, *args)
    option = method.to_s
    if option.include? '='
        var_name = option.gsub('=', '')
        value = args.first
        @@instance[var_name] = value
      else
        @@instance[option]
    end
  end
end
```

Thus, to retrive a setting, you would use:

```
a_setting = Setting.column_name
```

Comment: It is ok, but what if I want Settings to have field called, 'data_type'? So settings could be for example integers, floats, booleans.

Comment: @Igor: that would be useless. By using a column-based storage, you can have the database define the datatype, and you do not need to have a separate column for it. You are thinking about having one row per setting, and one column for the datatype. My example is a single row, and each column can be whatever datatype you want.

Answer (score -2):

Rails Migrations are used to create and update the database.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html